# How can I avoid this integer overflow?

Tags: c++

I was solving the famous leetcode question 4sum and I came up with an optimal solution but I am facing an integer overflow even though I have used long long int datatype.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> fourSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        if(nums.empty()){
            return res;
        }
        int n = nums.size();
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
                long long int temp = target - (nums[j] + nums[i]);
                int front = j+1;
                int back = n-1;
                while(front < back){
                    long long int twosum = nums[front] + nums[back];
                    if(twosum < temp){
                        front++;
                    }
                    else if(twosum > temp){
                        back--;
                    }
                    else{
                        vector<int> ans(4,0);
                        ans[0] =  (nums[i]);
                        ans[1] = (nums[j]);
                        ans[2] = (nums[front]);
                        ans[3] = (nums[back]);
                        res.push_back(ans);
                        while(front < back && nums[front] == ans[2]) ++front;
                        while(front < back && nums[back] == ans[3]) --back;
                    }
                }
                while(j+1 < n && nums[j+1] == nums[j]) ++j;
            }
            while(i+1 < n && nums[i+1] == nums[i]) ++i;
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

Here is the error message:
Line 12: Char 41: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -294967296 - 2000000000 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:21:41

Comment: Use a larger type than `int`? What have your beginners text-books, tutorials or classes taught you about the standard integer types in C++?, and their ranges?

Comment: `target - (nums[j] + nums[i])` is addition between `int`, even if you store (too late) into a bigger type.

Comment: You could try using a 64 bit integer: `int64_t`

Comment: That's `std::int64_t` from header `<cstdint>`.  But if you are doing leetcode to learn C++ I would advice you to do that first before tackling problem solving challenges at leetcode.

Answer (score 5):

Although in this compound statement

> ```
> long long int temp = target - (nums[j] + nums[i]);
> ```

the destination variable `temp` is of sufficient size, the actual arithmetic happens on the types determined from integer promotion rules, applied to `target` and `nums`, both of which are of just `int`.

You'll have to upcast them to a sufficiently large type before the arithmetic operator takes effect. Like this

> ```
> long long int temp = (long long int)target - ((long long int)nums[j] + (long long int)nums[i]);
> ```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. But for a test case of nums = [-3,-2,-1,0,0,1,2,3] and target = 0, I am getting runtime error(heap buffer overflow)

Comment: @BharathGowda: Well that's an entirely different question.  datenwolf correctly guided you to avoiding the integer overflow you asked about.

Comment: @BharathGowda Since you have an input for which your code fails, it should be a simple matter to use your debugger to find out why it fails. If you haven't used a debugger before then this is a good motivation to learn a very important skill.